# OneDrive login info

Tags: login, onedrive

I have my skyDrive app installed on Window 7 Pro and it is currently working fine. I switched over to my personal live.com account and then logged out and now my business live.com account is no longer available and the login page tells me that I am using the wrong email address for the business account.

Is there a way to grab the account email login off of the skydrive app?  I am not looking to steal the password because I know that but apparently not the correct email address.